# 3D Virtual Joystick movement-event with p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```js
// Virtual Joystick

/** Whether mouse movements move the joystick */
let movable = false;
/** The maximum stick deflection angle, in radians */
const MAX_DEFLECT = Math.PI / 8;

/** p5.js */
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL).parent('#canvas');
}

/** p5.js */
function draw() {
    background(6, 0, 163);
    const stickLen = width * 0.45;

    ambientLight(128);
    directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 0, -1);  // A white light from behind the viewer
    ambientMaterial(192);

    sphere(70);

    rotateX(-PI / 2);
    if (movable) {
        rotateX(map(mouseYRatio(), -1, 1, -MAX_DEFLECT, MAX_DEFLECT));
        rotateZ(map(mouseXRatio(), -1, 1, -MAX_DEFLECT, MAX_DEFLECT));
    }
    translate(0, -stickLen / 2, 0);
    noStroke();
    cylinder(stickLen / 5, stickLen);
}

/** Returns the mouse x position as a number between -1 and 1 */
function mouseXRatio() {
    return mouseRatio(mouseX, width / 2);
}

/** Returns the mouse y position as a number between -1 and 1 */
function mouseYRatio() {
    return -mouseRatio(mouseY, height / 2);
}

/**
 * Takes the mouse value in pixels, translates it to the center, and
 * returns the position as a number between -1 and 1.
 *
 * @param mouse either mouseX or mouseY
 * @param half half of either the width or height
 * @returns the position as a number between -1 and 1, or undefined if the mouse is outside the canvas
 */
function mouseRatio(mouse, half) {
    const mouseFromCenter = mouse - half;
    const number = mouseFromCenter / half;
    if (abs(number) > 1) {
        movable = false;
        return undefined;
    }
    return number;
}

/**
 * Updates the mouse position display on the web page, and allows the joystick to be moved only after the mouse
 * is moved to the center of the joystick (this prevents the stick from jumping to an extreme position
 * when the mouse pointer moves in from an edge).
 */
function mouseMoved() {
    const x = mouseXRatio();
    const y = mouseYRatio();
    const activationZone = 0.2;

    if (!movable && dist(x, y, 0, 0) < activationZone) {
        movable = true;
        select('#xy').removeClass('invisible');
    }

    if (movable && x && y) {
        select('#x').html(x.toFixed(3));
        select('#y').html(y.toFixed(3));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Virtual Joystick</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Virtual Joystick</h1>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <div id="xy" class="row invisible">
        <div class="col-2">X: <span id="x">0</span></div>
        <div class="col-2">Y: <span id="y">0</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code above create a virtual joystick. The goal is to change the event that handle the movement of the joystick. So when i click on the joystick(the circle) and dragged it, then the joystick move inside the canvas following the mouse. What should i change to achieve that? Any ideas would be very helpful.